# How to select ID by changing xml file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I’m trying to change an XML file by PHP.
It’s working but I can’t find how I can select the specific ID. any ideas?
For example, I would like to change the text of *id ken1*.
Thanks in advance!

PHP:

```
    <form method="post">
  <input name="ken1" id="ken1" type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$data=simplexml_load_file('display.xml');
$data->data->SText->ken1->text=$_POST['ken1'];

$handle=fopen("display.xml","wb");
fwrite($handle,$data->asXML());
fclose($handle);
}

$data=simplexml_load_file('display.xml');
?>
```

xml:

```
<kendisplay>

  <meta>
    <request>setData</request>
    <version>1</version>
  </meta>
  <data>
    <SText id="p1">
      <text>test</text>
    </SText>
    <SText id="p2">
      <text>test</text>
    </SText>
    <SText id="ken1">
      <text>test</text>
    </SText>
    <SText id="wait">
      <text>test</text>
    </SText>
  </data>

</kedisplay>
```

Comment: If you're interested in using the `xpath` capability of the result then try accessing like    
 `$data->xpath("//SText[@id='ken1']")` which if found returns a `SimpleXMLElement` which you can work with.

Comment: If I use:
$data->xpath("//SText[@id='ken1']")=$_POST['ken1']; I get a Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to actually use the xpath to update the document:

```
// assume $data has the fully parsed SimpleXMLElement document, as in the original post.
echo $data->asXML();
$ken = $data->xpath("//SText[@id='ken1']");
$ken[0]->text = "updated";
echo $data->asXML();
```

And output:

(First echo of original)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kendisplay>
<meta>
<request>setData</request>
<version>1</version>
</meta>
<data>
<SText id="p1">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
<SText id="p2">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
<SText id="ken1">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
<SText id="wait">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
</data>
</kendisplay>
```

(And second echo with updated value)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kendisplay>
<meta>
<request>setData</request>
<version>1</version>
</meta>
<data>
<SText id="p1">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
<SText id="p2">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
<SText id="ken1">
<text>updated</text>
</SText>
<SText id="wait">
<text>test</text>
</SText>
</data>
</kendisplay>
```

Remember the `xpath` returns an array of 0 or more `SimpleXMLElement`s which satisfy the path query.  So be sure to handle that appropriately.